# Как исправить глюки функции animate при нагрузке на браузер или как определить окончание нагрузки

Tags: jquery, animate

Есть скрипт в котором используется функция animate() она всего навсего меняет свойство left у нескольких элементов, но при открытии десятка вкладок или создании нагрузки на браузер хром иными способами эта функция начинает лагать и значения ставятся некорректно, вследствие чего блоки наезжают друг на друга, как это решить?

```js
/* global $ */
setInterval(function () {
  var length = $('#mytag .item').length;
  var left = parseInt($('#mytag').css('left'));
  if (length > 4 && left == 0) {
    $('#mytag').animate({
      left: 0 - parseInt($('#mytag .item').outerWidth())
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      complete: function () {
        $('#mytag .item').eq(0).remove();
        $('#mytag').css('left', 0);
      }
    });
  }
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: использовать любые библиотеки в данном случае невозможно по некоторым причинам а передвижение и так при помощи setInterval()

Comment: "есть скрипт" - может оно и так, но где он есть, что там в нём в это скрипте, как его оценить? можно было разместить на codepen или здесь. Если при открытии десятка вкладок тормозит скрипт, это может вообще быть проблемой видео-карты, компьютера и т.д.

Comment: setInterval( function () {

    if($('#mytag .item').length > 4 && parseInt($('#mytag').css('left')) == 0 ){

$('#mytag').animate({

    left: 0-parseInt($('#mytag .item').outerWidth())

    }, {duration : 1000, complete: function () {

        $('#mytag .item').eq(0).remove();

        $('#mytag').css('left',0);

        }})
}
    },2000); 

 вот такой скрипт и есть фукнция append работающая паралельно, она просто добавляет элементы но она не причем, написал чтобы было понятно что добавляются элементы

Comment: не фотматируется что то код

Comment: если даже это комп тормозит, и по сути так и происходит то зачем игнорируются условия, ведь каждый раз при выполении проверяется больше ли 4 элементов и равно ли нулю свойство  left и как поянть почему так происходит

Comment: уже не редактируется(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860659/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-animate

Comment: тут есть отформатированый вариант

Comment: https://codepen.io/Misha11/pen/OwxOro

Comment: но добавление элментов там отсутссвует, без сервера и джсон это никак а их светить я не могу

Comment: похоже на вашу логику (эстетику оставим за скобками) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMGpyM

Comment: примерно да, а вы знаете как это решить? никогда с таким не встречался и очень бы помог совет